# Best way to print values from mysql table by querying through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Most of the times in my pages, I need to print the value of only one field in the table, by using a loop. For example:

```
 <?php

 for($i=1;$i<=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
 {
     echo $row['name'];
     $sql1="select industry from table_industry where profid='".$row['prof']."'";
     $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
     $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
     echo $row1['industry']; ?>
 }
 ?>
```

For example, I have 5000+ record in table and the above loop will execute 5000+ times.

What would be the best way to print the value of the `industry` field from the table `table_industry`?

Is it the code I wrote above, or is there a method for faster execution?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an join in the original SQL to pull in the industry data at the same time?

Comment: Please show us the "outer" query, the one that "produces" $result.

Comment: note: get the mysql_num_rows into a temporary variable, don't call the function on every iteration; with some versions of the library, that results in an extra MySQL query on every call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JOIN

if you want to include only those rows with values in **industry** table then sql will be

```
    SELECT 
     table_prof.profid 
    , table_prof.name 
    , table_industry.industry  
      FROM table_prof 
      JOIN table_industry USING ( profid ) 
      ORDER BY table_prof.name ASC;
```

and if you want to include all values from table **table_prof** then sql will be

```
      SELECT 
     table_prof.profid 
    , table_prof.name 
    , table_industry.industry  
      FROM table_prof 
      LEFT JOIN table_industry USING ( profid ) 
      ORDER BY table_prof.name ASC;
```

i think this will help you...

Answer (score 4):

1. Avoid looping over all 5000 records. Use a filtering or pagination
2. Even more avoid nested queries. Use power of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) will help you out here.

With `join` you can instruct he MySQL server to combine different tables and access them in a single query, for example:

```
SELECT
  table_prof.profid
, table_prof.name
, table_industry.industry 
FROM table_prof
JOIN table_industry USING ( profid )
ORDER BY table_prof.name ASC;
```

Generally speaking, querying the database in a loop is a very bad idea and should be avoided unless you know exactly why you are doing it. Querying  in a loop can easily bring a database server to it's knees.

Answer (score 0):

To follow your logic, i would select all information load it in a hash and iterate in the hash, not killing the database.